# Removing this tag would make us more [product]ive

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I just came across the [product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/product) (x 3654) tag, and my lord, is this a tag worthy of burning in a pit of eternal fire.

In most cases it is used as a meta-tag to describe where the problem is occurring, which is immaterial in the context of the question.

It adds no special information to a question because it doesn't matter if the problem is happening in a commercial product or in the kernel complier of the Rosetta space craft, the poster seems to think that it's worthy of a question.

It's also off-topic for SO, because we don't care about the [product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/product) as a whole, rather the component software.

TL;DR We don't care where the software will be deployed, we care that there is a problem.

Comment: Have you checked that there are no questions concerning multiplication?

Comment: The tag says: "For the mathematical notion of product, use tag [multiplication] instead." And even in this acceptation,  the tag carries very little information in my opinion. Let's get rid of this tag.

Comment: Sometimes I think you guys search for this tags just to make witty post titles =)

Comment: @icebat Of course they do! Of course...

Comment: There are 22 results (as of this comment) for [[product] -[multiplication] multiply is:question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bproduct%5D-%5Bmultiplication%5D+multiply+is%3Aquestion), and more for multiplied/multiplication/times (though not all are about math).  (Markdown links seem to get confused by [].)

Comment: @icebat not really, but when I find one, I always come up with a witty title.

Answer (score 5):

> A product is a good that can be bought or sold. Use this tag to refer to products in an economic or commercial sense only. For the mathematical notion of product, use tag [multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiplication) instead.

The definition of the [product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/product) tag above suggests nothing relating to programming itself nor software but material.

The product tag is mainly use for products is the sense of multiplication concept, as a result of an operation/expected output just as for goods and/or services in most cases.

In its current state, the product tag is rather abstract and with no clear logical scripting contextualisation.

In my humble opinion, it is of no substance and should be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

> A product is a good that can be bought or sold. Use this tag to refer to products in an economic or commercial sense only. For the mathematical notion of product, use tag [multiplication] instead.

As indicated elsewhere, this is extremely vague, and does not appear to even be about programming.

It's also not clear exactly how this tag is supposed to help. Personally, I'd be no more likely to know the answer to a C# question that was also about [product] than I would be to know the answer to any other [C#] question. It does not help for navigational or analytical purposes.

Can we burninate this?

Comment: It is not vague to [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/8131/product?userid=3730754), he'll no doubt can clarify it for you if you ask him.  I'm not impressed with the research you do before you try to kill yet another tag.

Comment: @HansPassant If this gets featured, I'd be glad to consult him on the topic if he thinks it's a helpful tag. I personally don't see any use for it, though - it's extremely vague in my opinion.

Comment: @HansPassant 14 of the top 20 answers only have 1 or 2 questions in the tag. He has a lot of answers in it, but it's literally over 35 times more answers than the guy who has the second most answers in the tag. Most (14) of the top 20 tag users (including #2 and #3 by rep) only have 1 or 2 answers in the tag. I'm not sure what he's seeing that everyone else isn't.

Comment: @HansPassant Addendum: looking at his answers in the tag, [all but 2 of them have the woocommerce tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3730754+%5Bproduct%5D+-%5Bwoocommerce%5D). The remaining 2 should probably have the tag, too, because they're also Woocomerce questions. So he evidently got the badge incidentally to being a woocommerce expert (which he also has a gold badge in). In fact, [virtually all of his answers are related to Wordpress somehow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3730754+-%5Bwoocommerce%5D+-%5Bwordpress%5D).

Comment: @HansPassant I really don't think that this'll be harmful, even to the particular user you cite... as I said, we can consult him if this is ever featured, but as far as I can tell he's looking for Wordpress questions, some of which also happened to be tagged with [product].

Comment: @HansPassant: From the revision history of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56302514/revisions) just as several ones, it is clear the [LoicTheAztec](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/8131/product?userid=3730754) successfully got it pushed over the years but stop: this isn't a case to index; rather in the interest of the community, to restoring focus, essence for the intended goal. If such cases aren't checked, the future repercussions and impact on the community will be tremendous. As it stands, the is no single justifiable case for the use of product as a tag on StackOverflow.