# Closing up [shop]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Just ran into the [shop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shop) tag.

It has no wiki, 45 followers and 180 questions tagged.

I suggest to burninate <strike>and blacklist</strike> that tag as it is:

**1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

Yes it may describe the contents, but no it is not unambiguous.

**2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

No.

**3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

No.

**4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

No

## Related requests:

[Let's cart the [shopping-cart] away](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313944/lets-cart-the-shopping-cart-away)

[Burn the [cart] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258834/burn-the-cart-tag)

Comment: Yep, burnination is a one stop [shop]

Comment: Blacklisting is explicitly a separate process, which is **only** applied if the tag was previously burninated and has been recreated. It's also got it's own tag: [meta-tag:blacklist-request]. Unless you can demonstrate that [tag:shop] previously went through the burnination process, then I suggest you [edit] your question to remove the portion about blacklisting. I'm not seeing [tag:shop] in a [simple search of burnination requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bburninate-request%5D+shop).

Comment: The posters of the 180 questions should [shop] around for a better tag.

Comment: Time to close up [shop].

Comment: I believe that after a good cleanup, very little of this tag may remain, and it might qualify for the <50 question burninate. I've already put a lot of the questions on this tag in the [close queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=[shop])

Comment: Aside - not to be a party-pooper, but I thought we were not doing "puny" burmination requests anymore (I miss them, but "the Will of the People"...). Was I wrong? I even though I so explicit guidance somewhere.

Comment: @EuroMicelli: this applies only after a moderator adds the `featured` tag, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Seems like [product] should go, too.

Comment: @EJoshuaS: see [product] and [products] burninate-request: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285382/sell-off-the-product-and-products

Comment: Is it safe to say that everything tagged [woocommerce] can lose the [shop] tag by definition?

Comment: I'm closing this as a dupe of the joint request so I don't forget; though I'm gambling on the dual burn not being rejected. Doing both when they're effectively identical saves about two days of administrative overhead, which is stonks :p Will reopen if the consensus is to only burn [shopping], and get back to this as the next burn

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine thanks for featuring the dual burn for [shop] and[shopping], this one has been in the queue for 4.5 years :)