# Are the tags [product] and [rating] appropriate for this question?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-question

I think tags added to this question ([How to move Review stars under add to cart button in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56302514/6381711)) are irrelevant and I'm calling for a discussion to reach a consensus for rollback and or learn from the community why it should be the other way.

To start with, the post is off-topic because [it's not on point](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Secondly, it purely has to do with UI alteration to a WordPress [WooCommerce](https://woocommerce.com/) compatible plugin named [Dokan](https://wedevs.com/dokan/); there is clearly nothing about [rating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rating) nor [product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/product) but marginally [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) as WordPress is a PHP based Content Management System/Framework.

Edit history available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56302514/revisions).

Comment: You want to discuss the "tags added to this question", or to discuss if the question is on-topic or not for the site? Because if it's off-topic, discussion on the tags is completely irrelevant.

Comment: The question seems poor, but on-topic. `product` and `rating` tags seem more meta-tags than anything. I've removed them from the question.

Comment: @yivi: to discuss the tags added to the question please. I understand the post may be off-topic but assuming it isn't: are the `product` and `rating` tags relevant to the post given the intention of the author?

Comment: The most obvious way to look at it is: would this tag improve the chances of the question being answered? It seems that it got the answer before it was added. BTW, I removed it by the same reasons expressed here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285382/sell-off-the-product

Comment: How-to questions don't require a minimal reproducible example because the object of the question is to receive the example. Debugging questions require a minimal reproducible example because the object of the question is to find the cause of a given issue in a program and it is impossible to debug a programming problem without seeing the program that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285382/removing-this-tag-would-make-us-more-productive

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see how either of those tags are useful to describe the question, and how experts on [product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/product) or [rating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rating) could use these tags to find questions to answer.

To be honest, I find it hard these tags as useful on *any* question, but that's not what's under discussion.

I performed an edit to remove the tags. Maybe I acted on haste. If as a result of this discussion there is consensus on adding them back, the post can be edited again.

Regarding topicality: Meh. The question *may* be on topic. Probably too poor, although it *could* be useful for future visitors. Certainly not a gem to lose sleep over.

That the question does not include an MCVE is not really an appropriate concern, since it's a "how-to" question, not a debugging question.

Comment: The tag "rating" was not appropriated I agree… but the tag "product" refer to one of the main e-commerce Class components (and and to the Wordpress post type). It's very often used in this case on WooCommerce tagged questions when "product" is mainly involved. It allows to filter woocommerce tagged questions related to WC_Product main class (and Wordpress post_type).

Comment: @Loic Maybe you could post something of the sort as answer instead of a comment. Not in love with the "product" tag myself, but I think there is merit to your point of view.

Comment: Is better for me to don't answer here for many reasons. May be you are not in love with "product" as you don't answer WoCommerce tagged questions, like I do (and for info, "product" is the 3rd most used tag on WooCommerce tagged questions).